# Is it possible to include a Storyboard resource as a child of another Storyboard?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, storyboard, resourcedictionary

I know Storyboards are tricky with all of their freezableness, but is it possible to share an animation with multiple Storyboards?  Something along the lines of the following is what I'm trying to do:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Key="SharedAnimation" />
</UserControl.Resources>

...
  <VisualState Name="Animation1">
    <Storyboard SpeedRatio="1">
      <Somehow include SharedAnimation />
    </Storyboard>
  </VisualState>

  <VisualState Name="Animation2">
    <Storyboard SpeedRatio="1.5">
      <Somehow include SharedAnimation />
    </Storyboard>
  </VisualState>
...
```

Comment: As XAML is only a declaration of class objects and properties, it may well be possible to share elements, but doing so would make the file uneditable by tools like Expression Blend. It is far easier to do complex animations with Blend, than by hand, so best not make your XAML files non-standard if you can help it. Cheers

Comment: I get you, but for the very specific situations I'm thinking about, it applies to custom controls which wouldn't really need to play nicely in Blend.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it here because I currently don't have VS in this machine, but this might work:

```
<VisualState Name="Animation1">
  <Storyboard SpeedRatio="1">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="SharedAnimation" />
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: Does that work in silverlight?  I was under the impression that StaticResource only existed as a markup extension in silverlight.

Comment: All markup extensions correspond to regular classes that derive from MarkupExtension.